# Continuously differentiability of a 1D function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be non-decreasing, continuous, Lipschitz and $f'_-,f'_+$ (the left and right derivatives) exist everywhere. We know that (Theorem 17.9 in [1] or Theorem 4.2 in [2]) $f'(x)$ exists ($f'_-(x) = f'_+(x)$) for every $x$ except countably many points. Assume further that $f'_-(x)$ is left-continuous and $f'_+(x)$ is right-continuous, my questions are:

1. Is $f\in \mathrm{C}^1(\mathbb{R})$?
2. At those points where $f'(x)$ exists, can we define the second derivative of $f$ using $f'_-$ and $f'_+$?

[1]. *Hewitt, Edwin; Stromberg, Karl*, Real and abstract analysis. A modern treatment of the theory of functions of a real variable. 2nd printing corrected, Berlin-Heidelberg-New York: Springer-Verlag. VIII, 476 p. Cloth DM 38.00; $ 11.90 (1969). [ZBL0225.26001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0225.26001).

[2]. *Bruckner, Andrew M.*, Differentiation of real functions, CRM Monograph Series. 5. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). xi, 195 p. (1994). [ZBL0796.26004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0796.26004).

Answer (score 0):

Define $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ by $f(x)=0$ if $x\le 0$, $f(x) = x$ if $x\ge 0$.

Then $f'_-(0)=0$ and $f'_+(0)=1$, but $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.  If it were, we would have $f'_-(0)=f'_+(0)$.

As for the second derivative question, I am not sure there is much interesting to say.  For comparison, let's look first at the definition of derivative of a function $g(x)$ at a point $x=a$.
$$\displaystyle g'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}\;.$$

For this to make sense, one usually requires $g(x)$ to be defined in a whole neighborhood of $a$.

Now to make sense of the second derivative $f''(a)$, which is the first derivative of $f'(x)$ at $x=a$, one would similarly require $f'(x)$ to be defined for all $x$ in a neighborhood of $a$.  And $f'(x)$ exists exactly when $f'_-(x)$ and $f'_+(x)$ both exist and are equal.  So there is nothing special to say about one-sided derivatives when looking at the second derivative.